# Why does the compiler pick the extension method on string over implicit char array?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char, ambiguity

If I have `System.Linq` imported, I can use [this ToArray overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) in the following call:

```
var x = "foo".ToArray();
```

and `x` is assigned a `char[]` with three elements that are the characters from the string `"foo"`.  Then if I add a custom extension method in scope:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this T toConvert) => new[] { toConvert };
```

The compiler silently changes its mind and `x` becomes a `string[]` with one element that is the string `"foo"`.

Why did the compiler not complain about ambiguity?  I know some seemingly-ambiguous situations are resolved automatically by the compiler without errors, but I can't find any documentation or references about this type of situation.  Basically, it seems that treating a `string` as a `string` rather than an implicit array of `char` seems to be the preferred behavior...

Comment: Paging Dr. Jon Skeet :)

Comment: `"foo"` has a static type of `string`. `T` as `string` is a *more specific* match to the static type than `T` as `IEnumerable<char>` after having been converted first.  But Dr. Skeet can explain it better.

Comment: ToCharArray is what you want, but madreflection has it right for the extension method.

Comment: @jjxtra right, the question isn't about best practices, it's strictly about compiler behavior.

Comment: @jjxtra also thanks for the edit, I had removed the `this` to make sure I got my example correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first extension method you reference:

```cs
public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

Converts an `IEnumerable<TSource>` to an array (interface of generic type).

The second extension method you made:

```cs
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this T toConvert) => new[] { toConvert };
```

Converts any T object to a single object array. Since this is a generic type without an interface, it is preferred over an extension method taking an interface with a generic type. In essence, it is a greater covering surface of potential types to apply the extension on than the interface with a generic type. The compiler will prefer concrete types that match extension methods in favor of interfaces that match.

C# language spec, go about 60% down to find `Method Overloading`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction

C# overload resolution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/improved-overload-candidates

VB version, although applies to C# mostly:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution

Comment: Is there some documentation you can point me to that backs this behavior up?  Like I said, I can't find anything.

Comment: Added a link to bottom of answer

Comment: I'm sorry but a link to a Visual Basic reference is not too helpful.  The article is using language-specific keywords like `AddressOf`, which, at the very least, are annoying to someone who knows both languages and are totally bewildering to someone who doesn't know VB at all.  Surely there's a reference that uses C#?

Comment: I added a C# doc too that is shorter. The VB code samples are less important, the resolution points are the important bits.

Comment: Also added C# language spec, scroll about 60% down to find method resolution.